# How to number pages 1a 1b 1c, 2a 2b 2c and so on for different sections?

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I would like each section to have its pages numbered with letters 'a, b, c...', resetting to 'a' once I reach a new section, and its corresponding section number (normal 1,2,3,4...). For the most part, I will have sections with only one page, and so I don't want there to be lettering, just a number, but some sections will have 5+ pages where I need to have the letters.

Edit (Answering some questions in comments): All sections begin on a new page. Sections will have between 5-10 pages. 
Right now the pages go 1, 2, 3a, 3b, 3c, 4, 5a, 5b, 6a, 6b, 6c...6j, 7, 8, 10a, 10b...and so forth, but could change in terms of the exact number of subpages.

Any idea how I could implement this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Will each `\section` start on a new page? Otherwise, how do you handle the last page of section X and the first page of section X+1?

Comment: Do you just need the page numbers to *look* this way? That is, you don't need them to really be this way? It would help greatly to have a complete minimal example. This is going to be almost impossible to answer usefully in the abstract. There are just too many possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following process automates the setting of page numbers by section in the footer together with the requirement that single-page sections should only have their section number in the footer:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% \usepackage{alphalph}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,refcount}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\fancyfoot[C]{% Update center footer
  \thesection% Print section number
  \ifnum\getpagerefnumber{section-\thesection-lastpage}=1 \else
    \alph{page}% \alphalph{page}% Print page number
  \fi}


\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}{%
  \label{section-\thesection-lastpage}% Label last page of section
  \clearpage% Move to next page
  \setcounter{page}{1}% Reset page counter
  \oldsection}

\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
\lipsum[1-4]

\section{Another section}
\lipsum[1-30]

\section{Yet another section}
\lipsum[1-4]

\section{Final section}
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

The idea behind the approach is to set a `\label` at the end of every `\section` (actually, before the beginning of the following `\section`) and then condition on the `page` value at that time. Use of this `\label`-`\ref` approach is needed as you're dealing with the ship-out routine where page numbers can be fickle.

If you have more than 26 pages per section, consider using the [`alphalph` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/alphalph).

Answer (score 0):

Since everything is tied to the sections. I could set the footer to be the section number + the page number (alphabetized) and reset the counter of page number after each section.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\thesection\thepage}



\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{alph}
\section{First}

blah blah
\newpage
blah blah 

\newpage
\setcounter{page}{0} %reset counter, but only one page so set to zero so no letter beside
\section{Second}


blah blah
\newpage

\setcounter{page}{1}
\section{Third}
blah
\newpage
blah

\end{document}
```